# How to transfer the text file data from Flex to PHP or JSP?

Tags: php, jsp, flex4, tomcat6

I would like to save the text(paragraphs) in the StringBuilder and would like to transfer the String Builder to PHP or JSP to retrieve and save the StringBuilder info in the form of text file in Tomcat Server.

I am experiencing issue in transfering the text file info from Flex to PHP or JSP. Can you guys help me ?

Serenity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Flex side you just need to use the HttpService class to post your data to PHP, then save the data to the database from there.  This article pretty much sums the whole thing up:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/AccessingData/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fdc.html

Happy coding!